# How to convert this code into Xpath or Selector?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing Automation in SaaS products. Now, facing some issues this was the code

```html
<div class="action-buttons" data-v-335fe623="">
<!---->
<button class="mp-btn install" data-v-335fe623="">Install</button></div>`
```

Actually, multiple attributes are in the same values striking in this point to convert the value into Xpath or CSS if get that code can't able to click the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate this button by class names, text content etc.
Try this CSS Selector

```java
"button.mp-btn.install"
```

Or this Xpath

```java
"//button[@lcass='mp-btn install'][contains(.,'Install')]"
```